# entity framework 7 mapping attributes

Tags: entity-framework-core

Are there already mapping-annotations (attributes) for mapping foreign keys?

If no, are such annotations planned?

I've seen, that there is still a fluent-api for mapping foreign keys, but I have not found mapping-attributes for this Task.

Comment: None yet, but possibly as part of [#249](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/249).

Answer (score 3):

This is not implemented yet. You can track the work here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/107